# Cannot read data using DataSet in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have added a DataSet to connect with my SQLDatabase.  Test Query displays correct values but when I programmatically try to display the value of a certain field using following code

```
dim vrName= dsTest.Tables(tblTest).rows(0).items(0)
```

I get `Tables` is not a member of `dsTest`.

Please advise: how can I use dataset to read, write, edit and delete data as we use in WinForms?

Comment: What is the type of "dsTest" variable?

Comment: Error says the variable "dsTest" is not an object variable of DataSet class. Can you verify this for us?

Comment: No ! it says Tables is not member of dsTest

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the index instead of table name, like this?

```
dsTest.Tables(0).rows(0).items(0)
```

Between you can also retrieve column's value using column alias:

```
dsTest.Tables(0).rows(0)("column_Name")
```

Comment: yes but it gives error on dsTest.Tables part.  Saying Tables is not a member of dsTest.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug it, 
and this code:
 dsTest.Tables(tblTest).rows(0).items(0)

will get the row not the column.

Comment: Incorrect - `dsTest.Tables(tblTest).Rows(0).Item(0)` will return the first column of the first row.  OP is using VB.NET, not C#.  The equivalent in C# would be `dsTest.Tables[tblTest].Rows[0][0];`

Comment: That is not the issue !  Problem is VS generates error on dsTest.Tables